# How can I implicitly convert an object with an appropriate apply method to a function?

Tags: scala

As the question says I am trying the following (does not compile):

```
  object O {
    def apply(i: Int): Boolean = i % 2 == 0
  }
  val f: Int => Boolean = O
```

So I tried this:

```
  implicit def apply2Fct[A,B](applier: { def apply(a: A): B }) = {
    new Function[A,B] { def apply(a: A): B = applier(a) }
  }
```

But the compiler complains about *"Parameter type in structural refinement may not refer to an abstract type defined outside that refinement"*.

**EDIT :**

Due to the answer of *Jean-Philippe Pellet* I have to mention that I can´t let `O` extend `Function[A,B]` respectively `Function[Int,Boolean]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In case you haven’t thought about it and the code is actually in your hands, you might also simply do:

```
val f = O apply _
```

Or, putting the structural type explicitly to f, one could say:

```
val f: { def apply(i: Int): Boolean } = O
```

Comment: If "val f = O apply _" does the trick for you in context, then that's the way to go. But it's not so much an answer to your question as a way of avoiding having to answer it ... and it's none the worse for that.

Comment: Nice, `1 to 10 filter (O apply _)` works for me, although _Miles_ answer is more sophisticated, but I can´t change the code of `object O`.

Answer (score 6):

You can't do this directly for the reasons that Gilles gives on [ticket #967](https://lampsvn.epfl.ch/trac/scala/ticket/967). The problematic construct is the occurrence of the externally defined type parameter A in a bare argument position on a method definition within the structural type.

However, we can approximate the desired result by eliminating the problematic occurrence in favour of an internal type parameter coupled with a type constraint forcing it to be equal to the original argument type A at any point at which the method is applied.

To do this you have to modify the general form of the signatures of the methods you're trying to capture structurally from (nb. pseudocode follows),

```
def method(x : <<your arg type>>) : <<your result type>>
```

to

```
def method[T](x : T)(implicit ev : T =:= <<your arg type>>) : <<your result type>>
```

For your particular case we would need something like the following,

```
object O {
  def apply[T](i : T)(implicit ev : T =:= Int) : Boolean = i % 2 == 0
}

implicit def apply2Fct[A,B](applier: { def apply[T](a: T)(implicit ev : T =:= A): B }) = {
  new Function[A,B] { def apply(a: A): B = applier(a) }
}
```

Sample REPL session,

```
scala> implicit def apply2Fct[A,B](applier: { def apply[T](a: T)(implicit ev : T =:= A): B }) = {
     | new Function[A,B] { def apply(a: A): B = applier(a) }
     | }
apply2Fct: [A, B](applier: AnyRef{def apply[T](a: T)(implicit ev: =:=[T,A]): B})java.lang.Object with (A) => B

scala> object O {
     | def apply[T](i : T)(implicit ev : T =:= Int) : Boolean = i % 2 == 0
     | }
defined module O

scala> O(23)
res0: Boolean = false

scala> O(24)
res1: Boolean = true

scala> val f: Int => Boolean = O
f: (Int) => Boolean = <function1>                                                                                                                                                                                                              

scala> f(23)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
res2: Boolean = false                                                                                                                                                                                                                          

scala> f(24)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
res3: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Miles, very sophisticated! Your approach means I have to change the code of `O`, same problem as with the answer of _Jean-Philippe Pellet_, but I have learned something very clever! Thank you! I  generally like your answers. What a pity there is no double-upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried making the implicit conversion non-parameterized (not great, I realize)?

```
class ApplyIsF1( self : { def apply(a : Int) : Boolean }) extends (Int => Boolean) {
  def apply(a : Int) = self apply a
}

implicit def applyIsF1(self : { def apply(a : Int) : Boolean }) = new ApplyIsF1(self)
```

Comment: Sorry, you are right. Often find that declaring a separate class rather than a structural implicit solves the problem, but not in this case. The only thing I can suggest, then, is to make the implicit non-parameterized

Comment: After your edit, this compiles. Can you also make it generic, so I don´t have to rewrite the implicit conversion for every `A => B`?

Answer (score 0):

You should explicitly tell the compiler that `O` is a function:

```
object O extends (Int => Boolean) {
  def apply(i: Int): Boolean = i % 2 == 0
}
```

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned that, I know that, but that means I have to change client code, what isn´t possible right now.